# Getting user input when a user hits enter key jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input, enter

I am a complete beginner to coding and I have trouble with getting an user input when user hits enter key. I do have a submit button that takes user input when a user clicks it.

```
 <div>
      <div class="text-area">
        <li class="confirmation">
          <p> 
            Your Guess: 
            <input type="text" id="input" cols="15" rows="1.5"></input>
          </p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg submit">Submit
          </button>
          <ul class="lulu">
             <span id='total'> warm </span>
          </ul>
          <ul class="play-again">
            Your game has been restarted, submit a new guess!
          </ul>
        </li> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Html code above and jQuery code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".confirmation").on("click", ".submit", function(){
    // storing myVal as a number not a string by using Number();
    myVal = Number($("#input").val());

    // Push myVal to Array only when myVal is between 0 and 100 
    if (myVal >= 0 && myVal <= 100) {
        arr.push(myVal);
        newArr = arr.slice(0, arr.length-1);
    }
```

I tried to add

```
$(document).on("keypress", function(event){
    if (event.keyCode === 13){
        $(".submit").click();
    }
};
```

to js file but it did not work. It would be great if you explain how to add this feature and where (inside js file) I should add code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
<div>
    <div class="text-area">
        <li class="confirmation">
            <p> 
            Your Guess: 

                <input type="text" id="input" cols="15" rows="1.5"></input>
            </p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg submit">Submit
          </button>
            <ul class="lulu">
                <span id='total'> warm </span>
            </ul>
            <ul class="play-again">
            Your game has been restarted, submit a new guess!
          </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

And for your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    arr = [];
    newArr = [];
    $(".confirmation").on("click", ".submit", function() {
        // storing myVal as a number not a string by using Number();
        myVal = Number($("#input").val());

        // Push myVal to Array only when myVal is between 0 and 100 
        if (myVal >= 0 && myVal <= 100) {
            arr.push(myVal);
            newArr = arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1);
        }

        $("input#input").val("");
        console.log(arr);
    });

    $('input#input').keyup(function(e) {
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $('button.submit').click();
        }
    });

});
```

Or if you want you can check out the jsfiddle I made for you

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ilijamt/acfpwp1p/)

Answer (score 0):

While ilijamt's answer works, it looks like to me your real issues are with the HTML code. Cleaning up these problems will make everything else make a lot more sense.

I'm going to point out some of the problems, and then rewrite it in a better way.

- First, `<li>` and `<ul>` tags are really only for making lists (like this one). I think what you're looking for is a `<p>` tag for paragraph markers.
- You want to bind "enter" to an event, which generally means you want to use a `<form>` element. Instead of listening for a button press you can just listen for a form submit event.

**Example JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/k4sg3911/1/

Example HTML code:

```
<div>

        <form class="myForm">
            <label>Your Guess:</label>
            <input type="text" id="input" cols="15" rows="1.5"/>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg submit"/>
        </form>

        <p class="lulu"><span id='total'>warm</span></p>
        <p class="play-again">Your game has been restarted, submit a new guess!</p>

</div>
```

Example JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Binding not to click, but instead the forms native submit event.
    $(".myForm").on("submit", function (e) {

        // Prevent the default behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        // storing myVal as a number not a string by using Number();
        myVal = Number($("#input").val());

        // Alert myVal
        alert(myVal);

        // ... the rest of your application's code.

    });
});
```

I'll point out the important line,

```
e.preventDefault();
```

What this does is make sure that the form doesn't submit to the page and refresh the page. Essentially you're telling the browser "don't worry, I'll control this event myself." This is called on the `e` event object that's passed into the handling function.